# Voltage fluctuations, please help

Tags: electrical

I have problems of voltage fluctuations and lost my fridge today. At wit's end, as this has become a menace. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail.

Comment: Almost too easy for me to close (due to privileges based on specific tag), but the post I used as a close target has a good chance of getting you to the solution. Basically, a lost neutral results in your 240V loads correct but 120V all too high or too low *and frequently changing based on what else is plugged in* - which can fry equipment and wreak havoc. If you can post some voltage readings this can be likely confirmed - and in any case is a **utility company call - report an outage** (since it is one of the three wires from the utility "out"). They'll come out quickly (unless you are in

Comment: the middle of a major weather event) and figure it out.

Comment: I found a similar situation many years ago at a very large residence in a wealthy section of town. I called the electric company and they confirmed that there was a loose "neutral" in the electric vault of that residence. They corrected the problem right away.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that you lost an appliance tells me you have voltages **above** 120V, as described in the linked answer.  Generally that type of problem has 3 phases: I) realizing that this is the problem, II) figuring out what you want to do about it, and III) fixing it.  Phase I takes potentially weeks of time.   Phase II is entirely up to you.  I've seen people take weeks there; I recommend 30 seconds. Phase III takes an hour for the PoCo to send an emergency truck, unless they just had an ice storm or hurricane.

Comment: Turn things off to prevent destroying them. Have the power company check it, if it is a bad or lifted neutral they will fix it immediately. Ask for the diagnosis in writing and where it was found and what they did to repair it. If it was in the feed to your home all the damage including appliances should be covered by insurance. You might see if your neighbors are having similar problems. If you can measure voltage monitor it and make notes as to what you are getting.